# How do I enable all EPIC projects to use Perl's @INC?

Tags: perl, eclipse, epic

I have a set of intra-dependent Perl projects and would like to use [EPIC](http://www.epic-ide.org) to work on them. I created one Epic (Eclipse) project for each of my projects and I set dependencies among them using Project|Properties|Project References function.
For each project I also set Perl Include Path (`@INC`) in Project|Properties|Perl Include Path adding paths to the libraries used by this project.

The problem is the `@INC` setting does not seem to be transitive; if project B references project A, B's `@INC` does not incorporate A's `@INC` automatically. In effect I have to manually add paths from A's `@INC` to B's `@INC` to make Epic see all necessary Perl libs.

Can it be done automatically?

Comment: This looks like feature request to EPIC project

Comment: @Ivan Maybe it's by design? I have little experience with Perl and I'm not sure what the behavior in this scenario should be.

Answer (score 3):

If you're migrating to Eclipse and expecting it to use $PERL5LIB, beware that the -T (taint mode) seems to be enabled in EPIC by default. Just set "Perl EPIC"->"Perl executable" to simply "perl" (rather than "perl -T") to get your $PERL5LIB back.

It might be considered better design to define @INC in your Project->Properties, but in our department at least, $PERL5LIB is different from machine-to-machine.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It's a solution to a more elementary but vexing question "Why doesn't eclipse EPIC see the same @INC contents as perl from my terminal?". Note: taint checking is now a checkbox in the eclipse preferences for EPIC.

Comment: It is also important that the perl executable is really the perl you are using; i.e in my case I am running on Mac OS X with a custom perl install from macports, so "which perl" from the command line lists /opt/local/bin/perl. When I added that as the executable, my @INC suddenly started working.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of the PERL5LIB environment variable, documented in the [perlrun manpage](http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/pod/perlrun.html)?

> **PERL5LIB**
>
> A colon-separated list of directories in which to look for Perl library files before looking in the standard library and the current directory. If `PERL5LIB` is not defined, `PERLLIB` is used. When running taint checks (because the script was running setuid or setgid, or the **-T** switch was used), neither variable is used. The script should instead say
>
> ```
> use lib "/my/directory";
> ```

In your example, you'd need to set PERL5LIB to the union of `@INC` values in Project A and Project B.

As noted, if any of the projects enable taint checking (`#! /usr/bin/perl -T`), then hardcoding is the superior option.

Answer (score 1):

From [perlfaq8](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html)'s answer to [How do I add a directory to my include path (@INC) at runtime](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How_do_I_add_a_direc). You just need to use one of these techniques with EPIC.

---

How do I add a directory to my include path (@INC) at runtime?

Here are the suggested ways of modifying your include path, including environment variables, run-time switches, and in-code statements:

the PERLLIB environment variable

```
$ export PERLLIB=/path/to/my/dir
$ perl program.pl
```

the PERL5LIB environment variable

```
$ export PERL5LIB=/path/to/my/dir
$ perl program.pl
```

the perl -Idir command line flag

```
$ perl -I/path/to/my/dir program.pl
```

the use lib pragma:

```
use lib "$ENV{HOME}/myown_perllib";
```

The last is particularly useful because it knows about machine dependent architectures. The lib.pm pragmatic module was first included with the 5.002 release of Perl.